# TypeScript API: how to check that call expression uses signature from specific interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I use TypeScript compiler API to apply some transformations.

Say I have some package `my-pkg` that exports some interface `IExample`:

```
interface IExample {
  method1(): void;
}
```

Now suppose I have an implementation of `IExample`:

```
import {IExample} from "my-pkg";
declare const foo: IExample;
foo.method1();
```

How to check that `foo.method1()` expression is related to `IExample.method1`?

Apparently I can get call signature using `signature = TypeChecker.getResolvedSignature(node);`
But how can I go to the 'base' signature and check that it comes from `IExample` from `my-pkg`?

I tried to use `signature.declaration` and get its parent (class declaration or interface declaration) but it feels like a wrong approach because in this case I need to walk all parent extends/implements clauses to verify that parent inherits `IExample` somewhere.

Comment: Why close? What can I improve here?

Comment: Don't worry about it—your question has enough details in it. I've seen people vote to close compiler API questions a decent amount of times and I think it's just because they're unfamiliar with the topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the symbol of the call expression's expression (`foo.method1`), it should be the symbol for `method1(): void` in `IExample`:

```
const symbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(callExpr.expression);

// should output `method1`
console.log(symbol!.escapedName);

// should output `method1(): void`
console.log(symbol!.declarations[0].getText());
```

You will need to handle `symbol` potentially being `undefined` and there possibly being multiple declarations on the symbol (ex. multiple interfaces with the same name that are merged via declaration merging).

Comment: What if there is an inheritance? In case I have some class that implements `IExample`? Also I guess there is no method to automatically resolve where `IExample` comes from, right? So I should look into `import` statements to check that it's being imported from `my-pkg`

Comment: You can use `typeChecker.getBaseTypes(type)` to find out what types a class implements. Also, `symbol.declarations[0]` should be the interface declaration for `IExample`, so calling `symbol.declarations[0].getSourceFile()` will tell you what source file it's in.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. So if I get this correctly: if I need to know that call expression refers exactly to `IExample.method1` I need to get its symbol, check name, then check symbol declaration to see if it is `IExample` or find `IExample` in base types (recursively). Does it make sense?

Comment: @user0103 yes that should work. For speed you could consider not bothering with the type checker if the call expression's expression is not like `something.method1`—specifically, only consult the type checker when the call expression's expression is a property access expression with a `name` property that is an identifier with the text "method1"

Comment: Yes, I managed to do it with this approach. I grab method name, grab all base types of `something`, then I can check if `IExample` is one of the base types. Another interesting way was to utilize JSDoc tags, I had success with using JSDoc to 'mark' signatures for later transformation. Anyway, your replies gave me hints into the right direction, thanks for clarifying!